# How can I get the exact length of a string in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a strange result with:

`strlen("òàùè")`

How can I count correctly the string with **no-ASCII** characters?

I also looked at mb_strlen(), but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: What encoding are you doing this in? What is the strange result? What happens if you use `mb_strlen()`?

Comment: I get the number of character*2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`mb_strlen` will

> Return the number of characters in string $str **having character encoding $encoding**. A multi-byte character is counted as 1.

Your internal encoding is likely not set to UTF-8, so do

```
echo mb_strlen('òàùè', 'UTF-8');
```

Or set UTF-8 globally:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

And then do

```
echo mb_strlen("òàùè");
```

will give 4 ([demo](https://3v4l.org/YeEou)).

Comment: utf8 is not a valid encoding parameter. The list of valid character encodings is here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php

tl;dr:  The examples should read: 

`echo mb_strlen('òàùè', 'UTF-8');`
 and
`mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');` respectively.