# How to check actual unicode string length in SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, unicode

if we check the below string in PHP then result shows as below

> echo $Length=strlen('আমার সোনার বাংলা|আমি তোমায় ভালবাসি।');
>   Output:222

But when we check the same string in SQL Query then output shows 36 character long.

> Select LEN ('আমার সোনার বাংলা|আমি তোমায় ভালবাসি।') 
>   Length: 36

How can we measure actual character 222 length in MS-SQL Query??

Comment: Try to use DATALENGTH instead of LEN, maybe it's what you are looking for

Comment: The problem is that, according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php php returns the number of bytes. I assume the text encoding is UTF-8. The problem is that  SQL Server uses UTF-16. So in any case, even if you use DATALENGTH, you will have different results. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Microsoft Docs LEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql) `LEN` will return the length of the string.

If you want to get the bytes of the string, you need to `DATALENGTH` according to [Microsoft Docs DATALENGTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql).

**Additional information**

Equivalent for MySQL would be:

According to [MySQL Docs LENGTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_length) `LENGTH` used for character size with bytes.
According to [MySQL Docs CHAR_LENGTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) `CHAR_LENGTH` is used for "counting" the length of a result ignoring the byte length. This will see a 4-byte character as 1 length.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but DATALENGTH is giving the same output as LEN

Comment: The datalen function in SQL Server reports the number of UTF-16 bytes, php reports the len in bytes probably using UTF-8. You cannot compare the data length without taking in consideration the text encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first understand the difference between unicode characters and ascii characters. In your select statement, you use an ascii literal, not a unicode literal. In effect you are measuring garbage with that "test". In addition, you do not identify the datatype of whatever value you intend to measure using tsql. Your questions suggest that you are not using unicode strings in sql server - which is a big problem. And as others have indicated, unicode chars in sql server are always 2 bytes. To help illustrate the sql server side:

```
set nocount on;
declare @x varchar(50), @y nvarchar(50);
set @y = N'আমার সোনার বাংলা|আমি তোমায় ভালবাসি।';
set @x = @y;

select len(@x) as xlen, len(@y) as ylen;
select datalength(@x) as xdlen, datalength(@y) as ydlen;
select @x, @y;
```

Since strlen in PHP returns the number of bytes and since PHP uses a different type of unicode encoding, your goal is impossible. Perhaps you should be counting characters, rather than bytes?  Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914779/how-to-get-the-exact-length-of-a-string-in-php)

Comment: Each of those Bengali letters takes 3 bytes in UTF-8 (MySQL's utf8 or utf8mb4).  The space between words takes 1 byte.